# Can i use HttpSession object as an instance variable in Managed Bean. Getting NotSerializableException exception

Tags: jsf-2

I am using HttpSession as an instance variable like

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CountryPages_Detail {

    private HttpSession session;

    public CountryPages_Detail() {
        session = ConnectionUtil.getCurrentSession();
    } //end of constructor

    public String preview() {
        session.setAttribute("countryDetailImageNames", imageNames);
        session.setAttribute("countryDetailImages", images);
        session.setAttribute("countrySummary", countrySummary);        
        return "countryPages_View?faces-redirect=true";

    } //end of preview()
} //end of  class CountryPages_Detail
```

ConnectionUtl Class:

```
 public static HttpSession getCurrentSession() {
     FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
     HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

     HttpSession currentSession = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(false);

     if (currentSession != null) {         
         return currentSession;
     } else {         
         return null;
     }
} //end of getCurrentSession()
```

I want to ask is this right way? Actually i was using in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But when i changed it to `<param-value>client</param-value>`, then first i got the exception that one of my class is not serializable, after making it serializable now i am getting exception that

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    ....
```

When using server it was running fine. Why? I want to ask when we server in `param-value`then all our managed bean that are in viewScope(@ViewScoped) reside on server, and when we change it to client in  then all our @ViewScoped managed bean reside on client? Also if my beans are not in @ViewScoped, then does javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD element create any difference? Means STATE_SAVING_METHOD option relates to only @ViewScoped or it also effects @RequestScope or @SessionScopr or other scopes?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *absolutely* not get hold of external context resources like `HttpSession` as an instance variable. Just retrieve it in the threadlocal scope. You can use [`ExternalContext#sessionMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29) to manage the session attribute map without the need to have `javax.servlet` imports in your JSF code (which is usually a sign that you're doing things the wrong or clumsy way, whereby you're completely working your way around JSF without utilizing JSF's powers).

```
public String preview() {
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    sessionMap.put("countryDetailImageNames", imageNames);
    sessionMap.put("countryDetailImages", images);
    sessionMap.put("countrySummary", countrySummary);        
    return "countryPages_View?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Better, however, is to create a session scoped managed bean. You've there namely some strange and rather procedural and non-OO design.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Country {

     private List<Something> detailImageNames;
     private List<Something> images;
     private Something summary;

     // ...
}
```

which you use as follows inside `CountryPagesDetail`:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{country}")
private Country country;

public String preview() {
    country.setDetailImageNames(imageNames);
    country.setDetailImages(images);
    country.setSummary(summary);        
    return "countryPages_View?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

It's available by `#{country.detailImageNames}` and so on.

Comment: HHmm thanks for clearing me that it is not safe to do such things in the code:) . OK and if i want to get values from sessionMap on next page then i again get the sessionMap like `getExternalContext().getSessionMap();` on next page constructor and then use `sessionMap.get("countryDetailImageNames")` to get the value from map. Am i right? I am suing this instance variable so many places....(worried) Ok you mean whenever i want to put something in the session as i am doing in the preview() method, i always use sessionMap as you suggested. OK?